# Blazor MAUI error adding RazorClass Library project reference

Tags: blazor, maui

I have a .Net 7 Razor Class Library project that is used by my Blazor Server app (works great).  I then added a new .Net Blazor MAUI app (basic counter app) to my solution (so I can start learning MAUI).  I then added a Project Reference in my Blazor MAUI app to my Razor Class Library - so I can reuse the compoenets that I already built.  As soon as I reference the library I get the below error (see pic).  My Razore Class Library does refernce a Asp.Net Core Api class and does make calls to an API

In the output window I can also see:

warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.9' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8.1' instead of the project target framework 'net7.0-android33.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Any ideas what im doing wrong.  If I remove the Web Api reference from the MAUI app it seems fine.  I can add other Project References such as Data Access Layer but it doesnt like the Razor Class Library and Web Api project.  Could it be because it uses Authorisation maybe

Any ideas much appreciated[image]

I have managed to replicate the issue.  I dont think MAUI Blazor apps like adding a project reference to a Web API project

[image]

Comment: I see mentions of `.NETFramework` and `android-x64`. These are not compatible with .NET6/7, which Maui requires. I don't know anything about Razor Class Library, or the ASP.NET Core technologies, but you will have to change your library's target platform to .net7 (or .net core 6 or 7). This may mean finding different versions of whatever packages you refer to.

Comment: You can remove the package to see if it runs well. The package is suitable for Asp.Net 4. X, not applicable to Asp.Net 7.

Comment: Hi both, thanks for the great inputs.  I think I have identified the issue.  I dont think MAUI Blazor app can  reference a Web API project.  See attached screen shot of what I did with a brand new Solution that had three out the box apps.  Any ideas on how I solve this

Comment: You can access that API through httpclient.